# How do we find the average value of the following function?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, exponential-function

How do we find the average value of this function with the intervals $[0,1]$?

$$f(t)=10(e^{5t}-1)$$

Comment: Just take the integral from $0$ to $1$

Comment: Copy of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565155/find-the-average-value-of-the-function-ft-10e5t-1-over-the-interval/2566100#2566100

Answer (score 1):

> Well, in general:
>
> $$\hat{\text{y}}:=\frac{1}{\text{b}-\text{a}}\cdot\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\text{y}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

---

So, when:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right):=\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)+\text{n}_4\right)\tag2$$

Then we know that:

$$\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)+\text{n}_4\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)\space\text{d}x+\text{n}_4\cdot\int_\text{a}^\text{b}1\space\text{d}x\right)=$$
$$\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)\space\text{d}x+\text{n}_4\cdot\left[x\right]_\text{a}^\text{b}\right)=$$
$$\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)\space\text{d}x+\text{n}_4\cdot\left(\text{b}-\text{a}\right)\right)\tag3$$

Substitute $\text{u}:=\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3$, so we get:

$$\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot x+\text{n}_3\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\text{n}_2}\cdot\int_{\text{n}_2\cdot\text{a}+\text{n}_3}^{\text{n}_2\cdot\text{b}+\text{n}_3}\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}_2}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\right]_{\text{n}_2\cdot\text{a}+\text{n}_3}^{\text{n}_2\cdot\text{b}+\text{n}_3}=\frac{\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot\text{b}+\text{n}_3\right)-\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot\text{a}+\text{n}_3\right)}{\text{n}_2}\tag4$$

> So, we end up with:
>
> $$\text{y}\left(x\right):=\text{n}_1\cdot\left(\frac{\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot\text{b}+\text{n}_3\right)-\exp\left(\text{n}_2\cdot\text{a}+\text{n}_3\right)}{\text{n}_2}+\text{n}_4\cdot\left(\text{b}-\text{a}\right)\right)\tag5$$